# ncat --chat option? How to send a string/text to a single client and not to the other clients?

Tags: chat

`ncat --chat` option? How to send a string/text to a single client and not to the other clients.

Hi, I've tried different separator character syntaxes to send a string/text to a single client putting : :: . <>: <>:: between the client name and the message:

```
0) user5:string-0       # :
1) user5::string-1      # ::
2) user5.string-2       # .
3) <user5>:string-3     # <>:
4) <user5>::string-4        # <>::
```

But all other clients were receiving the string/text.

**NOTE:** the `(0)` .. `(4)`, just above in front of the commands is NOT part of the string/text. It's just for reference. The # is a comment and is NOT part of the string/text. It's just to clarify the character's used. Client and server real hostname is replaced by client-0.org TO client-4.org AND server. Client/server real IP's are replace by 255.255.255.251 TO 255.255.255.255.

I've tried the above separator characters : :: . <>: <>:: from BOTH the client AND server, but I'm getting the same result. Of coarse I could try each and every character on the keyboard combination.

Bellow is the output of 4 clients and server

```
*********************************************
server.org  :
Ncat: Version 7.60 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Generating a temporary 1024-bit RSA key. Use --ssl-key and --ssl-cert to use a permanent one.
Ncat: SHA-1 fingerprint: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
Ncat: Listening on :::31337
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:31337
Ncat: Connection from 255.255.255.255 on file descriptor 5.
Ncat: Connection from 255.255.255.255:59186.
Ncat: Connection from 255.255.255.254 on file descriptor 6.
Ncat: Connection from 255.255.255.254:34210.
Ncat: Connection from 255.255.255.253 on file descriptor 7.
Ncat: Connection from 255.255.255.253:44194.
Ncat: Connection from 255.255.255.252 on file descriptor 8.
Ncat: Connection from 255.255.255.252:58691.
server.org
user5:client-0.org-00
user5::client-0.org-01
user5.client-0.org-02
<user5>:client-0.org-03
<user5>::client-0.org-04
^D
^D
^C

client-0.org    :
Ncat: Version 6.47 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 255.255.255.251:31337.
<announce> 255.255.255.255 is connected as <user5>.
<announce> already connected: nobody.
<announce> 255.255.255.254 is connected as <user6>.
<announce> already connected: 255.255.255.255 as <user5>.
<announce> 255.255.255.253 is connected as <user7>.
<announce> already connected: 255.255.255.255 as <user5>, 255.255.255.254 as <user6>.
<announce> 255.255.255.252 is connected as <user8>.
<announce> already connected: 255.255.255.255 as <user5>, 255.255.255.254 as <user6>, 255.255.255.253 as <user7>.
client-0.org
<user8> client-2.org
<user7> client-1.org
<user6> client-3.org
<user0> server.org
<user0> user5:client-0.org-00
user0:server.org-00
<user6> user0:server.org-00
<user7> user0:server.org-00
<user8> user0:server.org-00
user5::client-0.org-01
<user0> user5::client-0.org-01
<user0> user5.client-0.org-02
<user0> <user5>:client-0.org-03
<user0> <user5>::client-0.org-04
user0::server.org-01
<user6> user0::server.org-01
<user7> user0::server.org-01
<user8> user0::server.org-01
user0.server.org-02
<user6> user0.server.org-02
<user7> user0.server.org-02
<user8> user0.server.org-02
<user0>:server.org-03
<user6> <user0>:server.org-03
<user7> <user0>:server.org-03
<user8> <user0>:server.org-03
<user0>::server.org-04
<user6> <user0>::server.org-04
<user7> <user0>::server.org-04
<user8> <user0>::server.org-04
<announce> <user8> is disconnected.
<announce> <user7> is disconnected.
<announce> <user6> is disconnected.
Ncat: 131 bytes sent, 1223 bytes received in 3474.43 seconds.


client-1.org    :
Ncat: Version 7.60 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 255.255.255.251:31337.
<announce> 255.255.255.253 is connected as <user7>.
<announce> already connected: 255.255.255.255 as <user5>, 255.255.255.254 as <user6>.
<announce> 255.255.255.252 is connected as <user8>.
<announce> already connected: 255.255.255.255 as <user5>, 255.255.255.254 as <user6>, 255.255.255.253 as <user7>.
<user5> client-0.org
<user8> client-2.org
client-1.org
<user6> client-3.org
<user0> server.org
<user0> user5:client-0.org-00
<user5> user0:server.org-00
<user6> user0:server.org-00
user0:server.org-00
<user8> user0:server.org-00
<user5> user5::client-0.org-01
<user0> user5::client-0.org-01
<user0> user5.client-0.org-02
<user0> <user5>:client-0.org-03
<user0> <user5>::client-0.org-04
<user5> user0::server.org-01
<user6> user0::server.org-01
user0::server.org-01
<user8> user0::server.org-01
<user5> user0.server.org-02
<user6> user0.server.org-02
user0.server.org-02
<user8> user0.server.org-02
<user5> <user0>:server.org-03
<user6> <user0>:server.org-03
<user0>:server.org-03
<user8> <user0>:server.org-03
<user5> <user0>::server.org-04
<user6> <user0>::server.org-04
<user0>::server.org-04
<user8> <user0>::server.org-04
<announce> <user8> is disconnected.
Ncat: 108 bytes sent, 991 bytes received in 3445.98 seconds.


client-2.org    :
Connection to server.org 31337 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
<announce> 255.255.255.252 is connected as <user8>.
<announce> already connected: 255.255.255.255 as <user5>, 255.255.255.254 as <user6>, 255.255.255.253 as <user7>.
<user5> client-0.org
client-2.org
<user7> client-1.org
<user6> client-3.org
<user0> server.org
<user0> user5:client-0.org-00
<user5> user0:server.org-00
<user6> user0:server.org-00
<user7> user0:server.org-00
user0:server.org-00
<user5> user5::client-0.org-01
<user0> user5::client-0.org-01
<user0> user5.client-0.org-02
<user0> <user5>:client-0.org-03
<user0> <user5>::client-0.org-04
<user5> user0::server.org-01
<user6> user0::server.org-01
<user7> user0::server.org-01
user0::server.org-01
<user5> user0.server.org-02
<user6> user0.server.org-02
<user7> user0.server.org-02
user0.server.org-02
<user5> <user0>:server.org-03
<user6> <user0>:server.org-03
<user7> <user0>:server.org-03
<user0>:server.org-03
<user5> <user0>::server.org-04
<user6> <user0>::server.org-04
<user7> <user0>::server.org-04
<user0>::server.org-04
^D
^D
^C


client-3.org    :
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 255.255.255.251:31337.
<announce> 255.255.255.254 is connected as <user6>.
<announce> already connected: 255.255.255.255 as <user5>.
<announce> 255.255.255.253 is connected as <user7>.
<announce> already connected: 255.255.255.255 as <user5>, 255.255.255.254 as <user6>.
<announce> 255.255.255.252 is connected as <user8>.
<announce> already connected: 255.255.255.255 as <user5>, 255.255.255.254 as <user6>, 255.255.255.253 as <user7>.
<user5> client-0.org
<user8> client-2.org
<user7> client-1.org
client-3.org
<user0> server.org
<user0> user5:client-0.org-00
<user5> user0:server.org-00
user0:server.org-00
<user7> user0:server.org-00
<user8> user0:server.org-00
<user5> user5::client-0.org-01
<user0> user5::client-0.org-01
<user0> user5.client-0.org-02
<user0> <user5>:client-0.org-03
<user0> <user5>::client-0.org-04
<user5> user0::server.org-01
user0::server.org-01
<user7> user0::server.org-01
<user8> user0::server.org-01
<user5> user0.server.org-02
user0.server.org-02
<user7> user0.server.org-02
<user8> user0.server.org-02
<user5> <user0>:server.org-03
<user0>:server.org-03
<user7> <user0>:server.org-03
<user8> <user0>:server.org-03
<user5> <user0>::server.org-04
<user0>::server.org-04
<user7> <user0>::server.org-04
<user8> <user0>::server.org-04
<announce> <user8> is disconnected.
<announce> <user7> is disconnected.
Ncat: 113 bytes sent, 1126 bytes received in 3454.57 seconds.
```